# Difference between adjective+noun and noun+adjective

Tags: meaning, connotations, adjective-order

> It was a speech calculated to appeal to the unions.

I encountered this sentense on the internet and got a question that

how the sentence will change its meaning or nuance if the noun and adjective switch their position, being as:

> It was a calculated speech to appeal to the unions.

Could you tell me how those two are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences refer to a speech that is intended to appeal to the unions, but they do it in different ways. In the first sentence the word 'calculated' is part of a longer adjective phrase describing the single noun 'speech'

> calculated to appeal to the unions.

In the second sentence the single adjective 'calculated' describes the noun phrase

> speech to appeal to the unions

If we these make these two ideas explicit to make them more clear you can see how different the sentences are:

> It was a speech that was calculated to appeal to the unions.
>   It was a calculated speech that was made to appeal to the unions.